# Running pentaho jobs through java

Tags: java, pentaho, jobs

I've been trying to find the download for the correct package/.jar files to run this code.

The code seems like it would work once modified (I took it off the pentaho github) but I also don't understand how it would say what it is doing in the console.
(Apparently this would happen)

Heres the code, I'm trying to use. I think it's the kettle.java.exec.src; that's the issue. I just cant find the correct file for it.

```
package kettle.java.exec.src;

import org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment;
import org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException;
import org.pentaho.di.job.Job;
import org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta;
import org.pentaho.di.repository.Repository;
public class KettleJavaClassExecutionJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String file="src/main/resources/J_KettleJava_Master_Job.kjb";
        Repository repository=null;

        try {
            KettleEnvironment.init();

            JobMeta jobmeta=new JobMeta(file,repository);
            Job job=new Job(repository, jobmeta);

            job.start();
            job.waitUntilFinished();

            if(job.getErrors()>0){
                System.out.println("Error Executing Job");
            }

        } catch (KettleException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

EDIT: Forgot to put in the error message on the first line!

"The declared package "kettle.java.exec.src" does not match the expected package "

EDIT 2: I have thought about running the job in command line, but then I would need to show the command line outputs in a JLabel/JPanel and I have no idea how one would go about setting that up

Answer (score 0):

"The declared package "kettle.java.exec.src" does not match the expected package" -> This error sounds like the package name is incorrect. You may check the package name out from the file system.